# How to automate data on a given time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app where users post stories and other users can like them, the stories with highest number of like rank 1st and that follows for top 5 stories, right now this happens on an overall basis, I want this to happen automatically every day, like for Monday the top stories will show only the stories with ranked number one on Monday Tuesday it will change.

**top_stories.html.erb**

```
<% posts.each_with_index do |post, index| %>
  <div class="post-panel">
    <div class="top-story-rank">
      <div class="count-button-wrapper">
        <span class="count-button"><%= index + 1 %></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <%= render partial: 'posts/post_metadata', locals: { post: post } %>

    <% if post.picture? %>
      <div class="post-picture-wrapper">
        <%= image_tag post.picture.url(:thumb) %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="main-body">
      <h3 class="post-title"><%= link_to post.title, post %></h3>
      <% if post.lead %>
        <div class="post-body"><%= truncate(post.lead, length: 190, separator: ' ', escape: false) %></div>
        <%= link_to "Read more", post, class: 'read-more' %>
      <% end %>
    </div>

    <div class="post-stats clearfix">
      <div id="post_<%= post.id %>_likes" class="pull-left">
        <%= render partial: 'posts/likes', locals: { post: post } %>
      </div>

      <div id="post_<%= post.id %>_bookmarks" class="pull-right">
        <%= render partial: 'posts/bookmarks', locals: { post: post } %>
      </div>

      <div class="response-count pull-right">
        <% if post.responses_count > 0 %>
          <%= link_to (pluralize(post.responses_count, "response")), post_path(post, anchor: 'responses'), class: 'response-count' %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**model.rb**

```
scope :top_stories, ->(number) { order(likes_count: :desc).limit(number) }
```

I have tried [Whenever Gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever) but that's not exactly what I want.

Comment: How you tried whenever gem?

Comment: You could use a chron job, and put the task in lib/tasks, and then whereever you're hosting, you can dictate how frequently to run the task.

Answer (score 0):

As per what I understand is that you want to have a day wise stories to shown on the page based on likes they got on that particular day.

Below mentioned scope will fetch the stories based on the likes for that particular day:

```
scope :top_stories, -> (number) {where("to_char(created_at,'day') = ?", Date.today.strftime("%A").downcase).order(likes_count: :desc).limit(number)}
```

**Note**: I have not tested the above code, so please check for syntax, it is just an example to show records based on that particular day.